# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-config'

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd

My Code: 
I have configured XML correctly, added all schemas but still getting error.

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation=
       "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/spring-context-3.2.xsd"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">
  <context:annotation-config />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
    <bean id="bean1" class="com.pojos.BookInfo">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mistake in specifying the location for the XSD for `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"` namespace:

Replace

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/spring-context-3.2.xsd
```

with

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
```

Altogether:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation=
       "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">
  <context:annotation-config />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
  <bean id="bean1" class="com.pojos.BookInfo">
  </bean>
</beans>
```